# Поиск с помощью indexOf() и сокрытие найденного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 100 элементов с классом `nameclass`.
Необходимо скрыть только те, в которых не нашлось, скажем, слово `qwerty`.

Пробовал:

```
if ($(".nameclass").html().indexOf("qwerty") != '-1') {
    $(".nameclass").css("display", "none")
}
```

Также стоит учесть, что элементы находятся внутри `div id="dsa"`.
В моём варианте скрывает все элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сокрытие элементов с классом `nameclass`, находящихся только внутри `#dsa`, и в тексте которых не нашлась последовательность символов `qwerty`:

```
$("#dsa .nameclass:not(:contains('qwerty'))").hide();
```

Используются [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) и [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja3z2wnq/).

Comment: Работать будет, но жутко медленно.

Comment: @Qwertiy как расценивать _жутко медленно_? Даже при 100 элементах речь о миллисекундах, а не о секундах. `$(".nameclass").filter(":not(:contains('qwerty'))").hide();`, например, должен работать ещё дольше. Можно провернуть через `for`, или через `map`, или ещё парой-тройкой методов, но это всё длиннее в плане кода и несущественно быстрее в плане времени.

Comment: 100 элементов - это не так уж много. Например, на этой странице 835. Дело в том, что jQuery не сможет передать подобный селектор браузеру и будет само проверять все элементы на соответствие. В варианте с фильтром, выборку по классу выполнит браузер нативными методами, а jQuery проверит лишь найденные элементы. Ну и ещё, ты сейчас в адекватном браузере проверил, скорее всего; а в IE картина поменяется. Кастомные jQuery-селекторы могут работать в десятки раз медленее браузерных, поэтому их стоит избегать или откладывать до фильтрации уже готового набора.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, для ненативных селекторов как `:contains()` действительно `.filter()` выдаёт ощутимо лучший результат в деревянном IE8. В Opera 30 и Firefox 38 результаты тестов почти не различаются, причем иногда длинный селектор выигрывает тест, иногда - `.filter()`. В итоге, если сайт рассчитан под пользователей IE8 (не знаю насчет новых IE), то тогда да, мой вариант плох. В противном случае, можно считать варианты равнозначными.

Comment: Да, я говорил именно про ненативные селекторы. К нативным никаких замечаний нет. Нашёл тест, который я делал. Он оказался не на filter, а на замену кастомного селектора нативным и подобные модификации. http://pastebin.com/33TRcaeq Разница в Яндекс-браузере - примерно в 15 раз, в IE11 - почти в 5 раз, но при этом в 2.5 раза медленнее ЯБ для. Но общая идея в том, что кастомный селектор проверяет всё что сможет, и если мы можем заранее как-то ограничить выборку, то от этого станет сильно лучше. Особенно разница 2 секунды и 37 секунд заметна в IE11.

Comment: @Qwertiy только что протестировали в IE 11. Вариант с `.filter()` отработал немного медленнее, чем с длинным селектором. Но опять-таки плюс-минус одно и то же. [Сам тест](http://jsperf.com/jquery-special-selectors-long-selector-vs-filter). Что я хочу сказать: если быстродействие **критично**, то тогда нужно выбросить оба варианта и переписать код без jQuery. Третий вариант в тесте именно про это (правда, в IE8 выдало ошибку на него, не знаю почему).

Comment: Подозреваю, что там ещё не было textContent, только innerText. Но не проверял.

Comment: Хм.. Попробовал немного поменять тесты, и получилось, что filter значительно хуже. Проверял в хроме. Странно. Подумаю...

Answer (score 1):

> Есть 100 элементов с классом nameclass.
>   Необходимо скрыть только те, в которых не нашлось, скажем, слово qwerty.

```
$(".nameclass").filter(":not(:contains('qwerty'))").hide();
```

Помещать условие фильтрации в первый селектор крайне неэффективно, поскольку приведёт к перебору элементов самим jQuery всемто запроса нужных у браузера.

> В моём варианте скрывает все элементы.

Потому что твой вариант - выбрать все `nameclass`, проверить наличие строки в первом; если нашлось, то снова выбрать все `nameclass` и скрыть их.

> ```
> .indexOf("qwerty") != '-1'
> ```

Жуть. Зачем загонять -1 в строку?